# Customizing the django allauth signup form

Tags: django, date, django-allauth

I am using the django allauth account forms and would like to customize my signup form to only allow users who are at least 18 years old to register. Here's what I have tried so far:

forms.py

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from datetime import date

class CustomSignUpForm(SignupForm):
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField()

    def clean_birthday(self):
        dob = self.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
        today = date.today()
        if (dob.year + 18, dob.month, dob.day) > (today.year, today.month, today.day):
            raise forms.ValidationError('You must be at least 18 years old to register')
        return dob

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2', 'date_of_birth')
```

settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'users.forms.CustomSignUpForm'}
```

signup.html

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {% if field.name == 'email' %}
        <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
    {% elif field.name == 'username' %}
        <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
    {% elif field.name == 'password1' %}
        <input name="password1" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    {% elif field.name == 'password2' %}
        <input name="password2" type="password" placeholder="Password confirmation">
    {% else %}
        <input name="date_of_birth" type="date">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Everything displays correctly and the user is required to complete all fields but at the moment any inputted dates are being accepted, even ones from the future. How do I fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was just to change 'date_of_birth' to 'birthday' in order to match my User model